# How to target specific field in Firebase / AngularFire when more than 1 level deep

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have an ng-repeat which looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">
    {{field.label}}

    <div ng-repeat="choice in field.choices track by $index">
        #{{$index+1}} <input type="text" ng-model="choice.value" ng-change="fields.$save(field)">
        <a ng-click="field.choices.$remove(choice)">Remove</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it is 2 levels deep it has choices inside of each field, I can't figure out how to remove a specific choice on click, I tried `field.choices.$remove(choice)` but it doesn't do anything, when I did `fields.$remove(field)` it removes the entire field, and when I did `fields.$remove(choice)` or `field.$remove(field.choices)` it doesn't do anything either.

Here is how `fields` is initiated:

```
var fieldsRef = firebase.child('Fields');
$scope.fields = $firebaseArray(fieldsRef);
```

Comment: Please post the controller code where `fields` is initialized.

Comment: @AnidMonsur ok I posted how it was created using $firebaseArray()

Answer (score 2):

`$scope.fields` is a `$firebaseArray`. But the `choices` property within a field is *not*. Therefore, you cannot call `field.choices.$remove()`.

The solution is for the `ng-click` to call a function in your controller to remove the choice from the field, then call `$scope.fields.$save(field)`.

```
<a ng-click="$scope.removeChoiceFromField(choice, field)">Remove</a>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.removeChoiceFromField = function(choice, field) {
    var i = field.choices.indexOf(choice);
    if(i != -1) {
        field.choices.splice(i, 1);
        $scope.fields.$save(field);
    }
};
```

Comment: Well spotted Anid. I'll also point out that nesting lists like this is something that is [recommended against in the Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html#section-nested).